# C++ linux detect all serial ports

Tags: c++, ubuntu, serial-port

Is there a good way of detecting all connected devices connected on serial ports on linux? Im programming in C++ but other examples are welcome as well.

You can just try to open every port and when it succeeds you add it to the list of ports but this seems not a really good solution.

You could go into the dev directors and since my serial port is a USB port I can check which ttyUSB.. files have been made. But this doesn't work for non USB serial ports since files for tty0 up to tty63 are always in this directory.

My example:

```
std::string port;
int fd 
std::vector<std::string>> list;
for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
{
    port.clear();
    port.append("/dev/ttyUSB");
    port.append(std::to_string(i));
    fd = open(port.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_DELAY);
    if(fd != -1)
    {
        list.push_back(port);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Serial ports are usually named `ttyS0` and so on.

Comment: This gives me the feel of an XY question, where your actual problem is X, and you think the solution is Y, so you ask for Y. Why do you want to know about serial ports on the system?

Comment: On 1 of the ports a zigbee device is connected. Since I want to make it user friendly I want to list all possibilities so that the user can pick. Normally if you plug in your zigbee device you should get exactly one port number returned to you.
@Hasturkun In my case since my serial device uses a USB connection it is named ttyUSB0.

Comment: @RoelStorms: I was mostly responding to the part about not working for non-USB serial ports.

Comment: in theory you could do the same for /dev/ttyX if you want normal serial ports. But again not the best way to go.

Answer (score 9):

The standard way of enumerating devices in Linux is to browse the `/sys` filesystem. In this case, you can to the following:

1. Enumerate all files in `/sys/class/tty`
2. For each directory `/sys/class/tty/foo`, check if `/sys/class/tty/foo/device` exists using `lstat()`.

   - If it does not exist then you are dealing with some kind of virtual tty device (virtual console port, ptmx, etc...) and you can discard it.
   - If it exists then retain serial port `foo`.

You should be left with a list of actual serial ports.

Comment: I get 32 devices via this mechanism. 2 are valid. You need to check that it's not pointing at `serial8250`, which is actually just the driver

Comment: On several of my systems, I have real valid serial ports where the `device` symlink points to `serial8250`... I'm not sure why you get so many invalid ones.

Comment: the 32 comes from the kernel config value  `CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_RUNTIME_UARTS`, I presume it's to support more than the default `32` (this is an x64 3.2 kernel).

Comment: If I just chek sys/class/tty/ttyS.. then I find a device folder in all of them. So that is probably how Petesh gets to 32 since ttyS goes from 0 to 31.

Comment: What recourse is there for finding /dev symbolic links to devices, e.g. those that are created by udev rules?

Comment: @Lotharyx You can use `udevadm info /sys/class/tty/<device-name>` which will give you `DEVNAME` plus any symlinks that may have gotten created for it.

Comment: @Celada Good advice, and it looks like there's a libudev library to allow C programmatic access to this info.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given that a number of years have passed since this was answered I am adding this answer. This answer works for later versions of linux.  It also uses the new `std::filesystem` introduced in c++17.  `std::filesystem` is available in earlier versions of c++ either through boost or in the namespace `std::experimental::filesystem` (use `#include <experimental/filesystem>`).  If using boost you must include compiled component `system`

This example also works out the where the symlink points to and returns it's canonical name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using std::cout;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

std::vector<std::string> get_available_ports() {
    std::vector<std::string> port_names;

    fs::path p("/dev/serial/by-id");
    try {
      if (!exists(p)) {
        throw std::runtime_error(p.generic_string() + " does not exist");
      } else {
        for (fs::directory_entry &de : fs::directory_iterator(p)) {
          if (is_symlink(de.symlink_status())) {
            fs::path symlink_points_at = read_symlink(de);
            fs::path canonical_path = fs::canonical(symlink_points_at, p);
            port_names.push_back(canonical_path.generic_string());
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (const fs::filesystem_error &ex) {
      cout << ex.what() << '\n';
      throw ex;
    }
    std::sort(port_names.begin(), port_names.end());
    return port_names;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated with `std::filesystem` and `c++17` code, based on @Nathaniel's answer:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>

using std::cout;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

std::vector<std::string> get_available_ports() {
    std::vector<std::string> port_names;

    fs::path p("/dev/serial/by-id");
    try {
      if (!exists(p)) {
        throw std::runtime_error(p.generic_string() + " does not exist");
      } 
      else {
        for (auto de : fs::directory_iterator(p)) {
          if (is_symlink(de.symlink_status())) {
            fs::path symlink_points_at = read_symlink(de);
            fs::path canonical_path = fs::canonical(p / symlink_points_at);
            cout << canonical_path.generic_string() << std::endl;
            port_names.push_back(canonical_path.generic_string());
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (const fs::filesystem_error &ex) {
      cout << ex.what() << '\n';
      throw ex;
    }
    std::sort(port_names.begin(), port_names.end());
    return port_names;
}
```